# filtering DocumentDb collection from Data Factory using unix-timestamp

Tags: unix-timestamp, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I am trying to select some documents from documentDB collection, in an incremental way, so every slice will select based on the "timeCreated" field of the collection. 
The problem is that this field (timeCreated) is in seconds since the epoch (1970-01-01) and I could not find the proper format [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

As project's assumptions, we are working with Azure Portal and without any programming interface, so the only solution I could think of is creating UDF in the DocumentDB that will transform the seconds field, to a dateTime field, but any approach that will only involve documentDB sql is much better.

This is the date data in the documentDB:

```
"serverTimestamp": {
      "$date": 1446130451707
    },
```

This is the way to use slice's startDate and endDate in the pipeline (from Azure documentation) :

```
"source": {
    "type": "SqlSource",
    "sqlReaderQuery": "$$Text.Format('select * from MyTable where timestampcolumn >= \\'{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm\\' AND timestampcolumn < \\'{1:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm\\'', WindowStart, WindowEnd)"
},
```

Is there another way, besides UDF, to format WindowStart/WindowEnd to seconds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Is there another way, besides UDF, to format WindowStart/WindowEnd to seconds?

As you mentioned we can do that easliy with UDF function. Then we can could use the function in the sql. As DocumentDB now supports range indexes on both strings and numbers. In my option we can format the field that we want to filter  instead of format WindowStart/WindowEnd to seconds. The following is the detail test steps:

1.we need to set up the [indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-indexing-policies#a-idcustomizingindexingpolicya-customizing-the-indexing-policy-of-a-collection) correctly for it to work.

[image]

2.Create UDF from with Azure portal

```
function epochToDate (ts) { 
   return new Date(ts*1000);
}
```

**Note:**  ts vaule is seconds, so need to covert to milliseconds

[image]

3.valid it from the Azure Data factory copydata Wizard

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly

Comment: This doesn't use the index and the data retrieval will slow down as more and more data is added! We need a way to convert the `WindowStart` and `WindowEnd` instead of converting our data