# Azure's CosmosDB - Deleting all documents in a date range

Tags: date, azure, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

I want to delete all documents created between the dates 2017-08-18 and 2017-08-22. I was told that all documents have CosmosDB's own timestamp under the field '_ts'. I tried using the document explorer to filter the documents using this query `c._ts > "2017-08-18"` but it does not return any document. I also tried `c._ts > 2017-08-18` without the quotes but that returns all documents, even those before that date, just as if there was no query at all. Looking at the documents, I do not even see a '_ts' field. Is there any way I can delete those documents?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_ts` is Azure Cosmos DB's internal Timestamp property

> The _ts field is a unix-style epoch timestamp representing the date and time. The _ts field is updated every time a document is modified.

If you want to query in a date range, we can do that easliy with [udf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming) function, more details please refer to another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43704166/filtering-documentdb-collection-from-data-factory-using-unix-timestamp?answertab=active#tab-top).

```
SELECT * FROM c where udf.udfname(c._ts)>'2017-08-18'
```

udf function

```
function epochToDate (ts) { 
   return new Date(ts*1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.documents.resource.timestamp.aspx#P:Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Resource.Timestamp

_ts gets the last modified timestamp associated with the resource from the Azure DocumentDB database service.

`[JsonPropertyAttribute(PropertyName = "_ts")]
[JsonConverterAttribute(typeof(UnixDateTimeConverter))]
public virtual DateTime Timestamp { get; internal set; }`

Its is represented as a POSIX or epoch time value. Its the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 (UTC), 1 January 1970.